# browser compatibility using css3 js

Tags: javascript, css, browser, compatibility

Im embarking on a project to build a new website.

From what I can see a lot of people are just going straight for css3 and ajax nowadays and not bothering to support browsers that dont have JS installed. They are using a number of workarounds such as enabling css3 through javascript in older browsers

Is this the ideal way now?

Comment: You could write various stylesheets for each browser and use JavaScript to load the appropriate one based on the userAgent that you recieve from the user's browser.

Comment: It depends on the project, target audience, and level of degradation experienced when the JS/CSS doesn't work.

Comment: "not bothering to support browsers that dont have JS installed" — would you provide examples of such browsers?

Comment: you can use modernizr http://modernizr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on the case. If you need to support older browsers like IE<9 and you need to do some fancy stuff not supported you can use a set of libraries 'faking' this new features for you. If you do not have to support older browsers or don't need to do fancy stuff you do not have a problem really. Check out http://www.caniuse.com to quickly see what features is supported in what browser (versions).

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good idea nowadays to assume that everyone has javascript installed?

Comment: Well, let's say that if you want a good user experience nowadays it's what most websites assume. There are a lot of so called Single Page Apps out there which won't do a thing if you disable JS. So I would say you can assume that the majority has JS enabled and if not, you cannot give them the desired experience. Of course, it's a good idea to implement a no JS fallback or a <noscript> tag at least to notify users about it.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be what is called "progressive enhancement":

> Progressive Enhancement means that each layer (content, followed by
>   markup, styles, and then behavior) builds upon the next, ensuring that
>   the core content is accessible along the way for less capable browsers
>   and devices. It’s not about specifics like whether your website works
>   with JavaScript, CSS3 Animations, or icon fonts. It’s not even about
>   technology. At its core, Progressive Enhancement means thinking about
>   a web page from the content out.

http://cognition.happycog.com/article/progressive-enhancement-its-about-the-content

start simple, and add Unobtrusive JavaScript and Css3 in a manner that, if not supported, they don't block the user from being able to navigate and use the website.

Answer (score 0):

The question of cross-browser development, JS and CSS3 support, fallback, workarounds and degradation is the question of time and money. In some cases supporting of the old or non-trivial browsers could take about a half of the time you spent on development. Time is money. If you not sure such browsers will share a lot of the amount of visitors (which are your potential customers), should this time to be spent?

At the moment even IE8 shares only 4.31%. And it supports JS.